# C помощью каких плагинов можно реализовать данный слайдер?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, animate, carousel

[image: ***введите сюда описание изображения***]

Столкнулась с проблемой реализации данного слайдера. Суть проблемы - перелистывание по 4 слайда с fade-эффектом, большинство плагинов, например, Slick, способны отображать только один слайд с таким эффектом. Поиск готовых подобных решений не увенчался успехом.